# Including other URL patterns

Tags: python, django, url

I have what I think is a pretty simple URL configuration for a public API I'm building in django:

```
# public API, in urls.py
(r'^api/', include('api.urls'))

# in api/urls.py
api_key_patterns = patterns('api.geoprocessing',
    url(r'^land-use/', 'landUse', name='geoprocessing_land_use'))

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<api_key>(.+))/', include(api_key_patterns)))
```

However, when I make a request to `/api/123/land-use/` Django's URL resolver cannot find a match.  When I debug the urls it has tried, it resolves the above to this:

```
^api/ (?P<api_key>(.+))/ land-use/ [name='geoprocessing_land_use']
```

Notice the spaces between `(?P<api_key>(.+))` and `land-use`.  Why are these spaces inserted for each include, and how can I get a match?

### Update

If I hard-code a url for `^api/(?P<api_key>(.+))/land-use/` I am able to get a match.

Also, if I add a character after the trailing `/` the URL match also works:

```
api_key_patterns = patterns('api.geoprocessing', url(r'^and-use/$', 'landUse',name='geoprocessing_land_use'))
urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^(?P<api_key>(.+))/l', include(api_key_patterns)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('api.geoprocessing',
    url(r'^land-use/(?P<api_key>(.+))/$', 'landUse',
        name='geoprocessing_land_use'))
)
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish by including a pattern when it doesn't seem like you need to be doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like using a `(.+)` group within my regular expression was forcing the django URL resolver to look for a character that wasn't there.  This always parses when there are characters following the trailing slash, but when this group sits at the end of the url segment, a space is tagged at the end.

I resolved this by exchanging the `(.+)` group with a simple word matcher `\w+`:

```
(r'^api/(?P<api_key>\w+)/', include('api.api')),
```